# Why does my code that interrupts a thread leak?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, interrupt

This is a very simplified example, so please bear with me for a moment....

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
struct foo {
    boost::thread t;
    void do_something() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }

    void thread_fun(){
        try {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
            {
                boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di;
                do_something();
            }
        } catch (boost::thread_interrupted& e) {}
    }
    void interrupt_and_restart() {
        t.interrupt();
        //if (t.joinable()) t.join(); // X
        t = boost::thread(&foo::thread_fun,this);           
    }
};

int main(){
    foo f;
    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        f.interrupt_and_restart();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(3));
    }
}
```

When I run this code on linux and look at the memory consumption with `top` I see a constant increase in virtual memory used (and my actual code crashes at some point). Only if I join the thread after interrupting it, the memory usage stays constant. Why is that?

Comment: All threads needs some memory for bookkeeping (like storing the return value of the *real* thread function). If you don't `join` the thread, that memory will never be reclaimed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude for some reason I was under the impression that if the thread finishes with `thread_fun` it cleanly terminates whether I join it or not. I already know that it is wrong, but dont completely understand it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude offtopic for this question: I also observed that this particular thread ( i mean the one in the real code, but It looks quite similar) to my surprise uses much more memory than any other thread in my system and the only difference I am aware of is that I interrupt it, but that would be a completely different question...

Comment: @user5226582 the question you link is about C#. And yes, it is only the sleeping that should get interrupted, not the actual work (calling `doSomething`)

Answer (score 1):

You are not joining the thread: because of this, some resources needed to keep track of the thread stay allocated.

A non joined thread still uses some system resources even if it has been terminated (e.g. its thread id is still valid).
Also, the system may impose a limit on the number of threads simultaneously allocated, and non joined threads count toward that limit.
Using `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` on my Linux VM gives me 23207 threads.

The latest versions of boost should actually crash when you destroy a joinable thread object, while older versions are happy to comply with the destruction request.